# How do you name a face in glTF export so that it can be replaced at runtime by THREE.js?

Tags: three.js

I'm able to load a glTF model into THREE.js, but I'm not sure how to proceed with "finding" the right face. Ideally, I could name the face in Blender and after exporting and importing into THREE.js I could do something like `mesh.getFaceByName('faceName')`. I imagine this would allow me to replace the Material (texture) for that particular face. However, I'm stuck at trying to find the correct face.

Comment: It's not possible to name an individual face in Blender. In `three.js` it's not possible to render an arbitrary face with a different material. You would have to use [BufferGeometry.groups](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.groups) for this. But applying a group for each face is inefficient. Can you please explain what you actually want to achieve in your app? There is probably a different way than what you have in mind.

Comment: One option might be to use vertex colors on that face - both glTF and Blender allow multiple sets of vertex colors if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. To elaborate, I would like to allow a customer to place an image onto a surface of a mesh. For instance, if I had a cube, I would like to name a single face ahead of time that the user can apply an image to.

Comment: One way I found to accomplish this was splitting the mesh out into separate mesh objects in Blender. Then I can target a particular mesh object with `scene.getObjectByName`.